# Get frequency of a factor variable in R considering another variable as indicator

Tags: r

I want to compute frequency of a factor variable considering another variable as reference. The `dput()` version of my data frame is the next:

```
structure(list(ID = c("0001", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0005", 
"0006", "0007", "0008", "0009", "0010", "0011", "0012", "0013", 
"0014", "0015", "0016", "0017", "0018", "0019", "0020"), Class = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), 
    Segment = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4)), .Names = c("ID", "Class", "Segment"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

And it shows like this:

```
ID  Class   Segment
0001    A   1
0002    A   1
0003    A   1
0004    B   1
0005    C   1
0006    B   2
0007    B   2
0008    C   2
0009    C   2
0010    A   2
0011    D   3
0012    D   3
0013    D   3
0014    E   3
0015    E   3
0016    A   4
0017    A   4
0018    A   4
0019    E   4
0020    E   4
```

I want to compute the frequency of `Class` considering each levels in `Segment`. `Segment` has 4 levels 1,2,3 and for they I want to compute the frequency of `Class`, I wish to get something like this:

```
Segment:1
A B C
3 1 1

Segment:2
A B C
1 2 2

Segment:3
D E
3 2

Segment:4
A E
3 2
```

I would like to get something like this, but I can't find a way in R to compute it. Thanks in advance.

**The solution**

It was easy like all in R, `ftable()` function solve my problem:

```
ftable(d[,c(3,2)])
        Class A B C D E
Segment                
1             3 1 1 0 0
2             1 2 2 0 0
3             0 0 0 3 2
4             3 0 0 0 2
```

Comment: You're just looking for the function `table`.

Comment: Dear @joran `table` and `ftable` solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: @Duck, after a couple of hours you will be entitled (and encouraged) to post an answer to your own question ... (@joran doesn't need the reputation, and if he wants it he can go ahead and post his comment as an answer)